# Angular: How to Manipultate a DataResponse

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Goodmoring, My Scenario is this:

We have a Component:
***homepage.component.ts***

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(//Some Code){
      this.apiService.callingHTTP().then();
    }else{
      //Some Cde
    }
  }
```

Now let's go inside the Service: ***apiService.service.ts***

```
return this.HttpClient.get(//Some Code).toPromise().then(
       returnValue => {
         this.otherService.ExecProcess1(returnValue);
         this.otherService.ExecProcess2(returnValue);
         this.otherService.ExecProcess3(returnValue);
       }
    );
```

**Perfect now the real problems begin!**

Let's go inside the Service: ***otherService.service.ts*** and start to manipulate / modify everything that is necessary

```
ExecProcess1(returnValue){
  console.log('Show the Array Values');
  console.log(returnValue.interestedData);

  returnValue.interestedData.forEach(function (element, index, list){
     //Some Code

     let temporaryVariable = externalFunction(returnValue.interestedData.Value);
  }

}
```

**Now I have a lot of questions for you:**

1) I tried to write `this.anotherService.temporaryFunction(returnValue.interestedData.Value);`

We go to: ***anotherService*** and run ***temporaryFunction***

`externalFunction(params) {
   \\Some Code;
}`

But when I go to Run the **Debugger tells me**: "***this is undefined***" I don't know why, please explain it to me!

2) The **IDE tells me**: "***Why don't you create an internal function??***" like that:

```
ExecProcess1(returnValue){
  console.log('Show the Array Values');
  console.log(returnValue.interestedData);

  returnValue.interestedData.forEach(function (element, index, list){
     //Some Code

     let temporaryVariable = externalFunction(returnValue.interestedData.Value);
  }

  function externalFunction(params){
        //Some Code;
  }

}
```

I **replied to the IDE**: "***ok okay it could be but why "externalFunction" I can not put it in another external service??***"

Can anyone help me??

Thanks :)

Comment: Potentially clean up/review your question. For instance you've referenced `this.anotherService.temporaryFunction` but that call isn't visible in any of the code you've posted above. If you're getting a `this` is undefined error it sounds like you're having a scoping issue.

Comment: Yes my huge problems is "this is undefined" ;
And some like you have told me that it is a problem of scopping and managing the keyword `"this."` but by looking on the internet and reading the guides I have not understood how the `"this"` keywork is managed.

Comment: `this` is relative to the scope of your JS/Typescript code. When working with angular generally `this` refers to variables/scoping in that class. When you `function myFunction() { this... }` then it's actually scoped to inside of that function while arrow functions actually retain the parents scope. Again without more code it's not possible to provide further clarity.

Comment: thanks guy i tried to study `This.` and i try to understand the `Scopping Issues`